# Editing HTML in Joomla

Tags: html, css, joomla, footer

I hope someone can help me.
I am making a new site in Joomla and I have got some problems with my footer. 
I need it to be continuous, with the width set to 100% of the screen. I know how to do it in HTML, with `clear: both` and `position: absolute` attributes, and then put the footer div outside the wrapper. However, I can't seem to find the HTML files so that I can edit them.

I am using the Yootheme template; Nano.

You can visit my homepage [here](http://webkjaer.dk/)

Can someone help me? Or is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't had much fun altering the Yoothemes, but here's two suggestions:

1. The CSS you're interested in is at `templates/yoo_nano/warp/css/layout.css`
2. Install Firebug to assist you while adjusting the CSS for #footer to suit your needs.

Comment: Iam using firebug, but the only way i know how to solve this, is by moving the footer div out of the wrapper, cant do that by accesing the ccs files.

Comment: You'll likely have to look at templates/yoo_nano/index.php to make that change.

Comment: Can you tell me what atributes i need to add to the css then?

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit index.ph available here:

> /templates/yoo_nano/index.php

And add your HTML code at the desired position.